# Scraping Facebook posts data using PHP Goutte?

Tags: php, facebook, web-scraping, web-crawler, goutte

I need to scrape post id, number of likes, number of comments, and username.
by using php code and I am currently using library Goutte.
How do I get post details? Is it possible using php goutte or do I have to use FB Graph API?

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';//require the vendor/autoload.php file.

$client = new \Goutte\Client();//create a new client.
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.facebook.com/username/');//go to site
```

Comment: Now check the edited question please

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape. Use the API.

Comment: need to use selenium

Answer (score 0):

You are forced to use the Facebook Graph API. Scraping users’ profile pages can give basic information about them, who they’re friends with, and what photos they’ve posted.
Facebook realise the potential harm to user privacy from allowing anyone to scrape profiles. For this reason, most elements of a typical Facebook profile are set to private, meaning that they can’t be viewed by anyone who that user hasn’t added as a friend. If you try to scrape a random person’s Facebook account, you may not be able to pull much information other than their name, their profile picture, and any old posts on their timeline which haven’t been made private. So, I advice you to use the Graph API, take a look to the docs from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/). If you have any problem with the Graph API, post another question.